# Java ResourceBundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I haven't programmed in Java for months and I have a small application to develop for my own usage. I am stuck on ResourceBundle ! I remember it to be very easy to use, so I guess my problem is something very easy to solve but needs new eyes :)

```
Locale frLocale = new Locale("fr","CA");
Locale enLocale = new Locale("en","CA");

String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("current dir = " + dir); // current dir = D:\RP1.8.2

Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(dir,"test.properties");
System.out.println("Path : "+p.toAbsolutePath().toString()); // Path : D:\RP1.8.2\test.properties

boolean exists = Files.exists(p);
System.out.println("File found: "+exists); // File found: true

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(p.toAbsolutePath().toString());
/* Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name D:\RP1.8.2\test.properties, locale fr_CA */

String title = bundle.getString("main.title");
System.out.println("Titre = "+title);
```

So my properties file exists but the ResourceBundle doesnt find it ... weird.
In the user directory i have 3 files:
test.properties, test_fr.properties and test_fr_CA.properties

Any clue for me ? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure resource bundles aren't file names or paths but resources, they have Java-like names.  Normally you put them on the class path and not a direct link.  So what you want to do is print out your class path so we can see that the resource file is on the path.

Comment: Hi markspace and thanks for your comment. I have checked the Oracle documentation ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html ) and they don't mention the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to getBundle is not a file name, and in fact must not be a file name.  ResourceBundle files are *application resources,* and need to be placed in the same location as your compiled classes.  (In fact, a ResourceBundle can be an actual Java class instead of a properties file.)  For example:

```
build
└─classes
  └─com
    └─example
      └─myapp
        ├─MyWindow.class
        ├─MyDataImporter.class
        ├─test.properties
        ├─test_fr.properties
        └─test_fr_CA.properties
```

Code:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.myapp.test");
```

Comment: Hi VGR and thanks! Yes, this is the solution !
As you said, it's not a file, but a class or properties file, in the compiled class / jar file.
Thanks a thousand ! I couldn't have slept well not solving this !

Answer (score -1):

If its a maven project then I would right click the project and under "M2 tools" I would select generate artifacts (check for updates) then click "generate OSGI bundles"